# Debug while webcraping with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to webscrape a website with scrapy (with a 10s download delay + AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True + ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True). When I run the command:

```
scrape crawl myspider -o mydata.csv
```

I get this output for multiple "lines" until 405:

```
[protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 4 without any user agent to enforce it on.
```

and also:

```
[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 https://www.funda.nl/koop/utrecht/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Why can't scrapy scrape this website?

and this is the dumping stats (if useful):

```
2019-11-03 00:33:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 417,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23402,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/405': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 13.42723,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 2, 23, 33, 55, 12777),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/405': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 61,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'memusage/max': 51818496,
 'memusage/startup': 51818496,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/405': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 2, 23, 33, 41, 585547)}
```

Comment: as I know most modules uses own name in HTTP header `User-Agent` so servers can easily recognize script and block it.

Comment: when I use module `requests` with standard headers then I get `405`. But if I add header `'User-Agent'` with full name of my browser then I get `200`. The same can be with `scrapy`. BTW: some pages work when you use short (but incorrect) value in header - like `"Mozilla/5.0"` - but this page needs full name.

Comment: apparently I get a 200 response, but my script gets blocked after that because of captcha?

Comment: server may check different elements to recognize script. First you would have to set correct [USER_AGENT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent). But if it is not enought then you may have to change it in every request. You may need also use [proxy servers](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpproxy-enabled). On some pages you can find lists with [free proxy servers](https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS) but sometimes they are not acctual or scraped server already know these servers and blocks them.

Comment: scrapy module for [random user agent](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to emulate exactly same request as a real browser does

```
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

yield scrapy.Request('https://www.funda.nl/koop/utrecht/', headers=headers)
```

Comment: sorry if this is a beginner question, but do you have an example of how I would include the headers in my scrapy code? would I put it inside def parse(self, response)?

Comment: Put it inside "start_requests" function, if doesn't exist than create new one, it will execute automatically inside a spider.